# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ace/edit_session'

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I have embedded ace editor in my angular project. But in my ts file it is always telling ace/edit_session module not found. I have included require in tsconfig.

My ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var ace : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    var EditSession = require("ace/edit_session").EditSession;
    var js = new EditSession("some js code");
    var css = new EditSession(["some", "css", "code here"]);
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/python");
    editor.setOptions({
      'fontSize': 17,
      'behavioursEnabled': true,
      'wrapBehavioursEnabled': false,
      'wrap': true,
      'indentedSoftWrap': false,
      'enableLiveAutocompletion': true,
   });

// and then to load document into editor, just call
editor.setSession(js);

  }

}
```

Comment: Try declaring ace as var ace = require('ace')

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the way you include ace in your page which is not shown in the code snippet above.

But since `ace.edit` already works for you, instead of `require("ace/edit_session").EditSession;` try using `ace.EditSession` or `ace.require("ace/edit_session")` which should be present on recent versions of ace.

Comment: I have included the ace js source file as script in index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use not by including the source file ace js as a script in index.htm

For example, another way in Angular:

1) Install "ace-builds" using npm or yarn

```
npm i ace-builds
```

2) import ace to your component

[image]

3) initialize editor in your component

[image]

4) inside HTML page:

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

5) do not forget to specify the size of the editor in "css" so that it is visible on the page. 
css:

```
#editor {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```